# _wcsicmp with Japanese characters returning wrong result

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, string-comparison, cjk

```
_wcsicmp(_T("2"), _T("課")) == 30127 //(some positive number)
_wcsicmp(_T("2"), _T("亜")) == -20027 //(some negative number)
```

in both cases the result should be negative, but in the first case the result is positive, why?

```
int code1 = 0x41 //2
int code2 = 0x4e9c //課
int code3 = 0x8ab2 //亜
```

Comment: It returns -35456 on my machine.  After I fixed the compile errors by prefixed L to turn them into wide string literals and ensured the source code was saved with the utf8 encoding with a BOM.  Why you don't get a compile error is hard to guess.

Comment: yes, I am also using _T("") this convention only. this is not the copied code but just statements to show the problem. Its strange you are getting negative values in both statement. As on American english machine, in VS2017 and VS2015 both I am getting positive values of the first statement.

Comment: I don't understand negative vote, if you don't know the answer its ok, I also don't know. But what is wrong with the question, I am getting wrong results with WINAPI and asked for help what could be wrong.

Comment: *"I don't understand negative vote"* That one's easy: *"this is not the copied code but just statements to show the problem"* Show the actual code you have difficulty with, preferably in the form of a [mcve]; not a mangled example that fails to compile.

Comment: you mean this "_wcsicmp("2", "課")" requires a full code, and a negative vote for missing _T.